# How to randomly return 100,000 data entries from SQL Server database using SQL query?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

Would the syntax be:

```
ORDER BY RAND (9886)
LIMIT 100000
```

Answer (score 2):

No.  You could use the syntax:

```
select top 100000 t.*
from t
order by newid();
```

Comment: (1) would "select top 100000" give me the first 100000 or a random sample of 100000 out of the population (2) Does your SQL book teach SQL to beginners?

Comment: @cartesian_plane67 . . . (1) This query would select 100,000 rows, equivalent to the query you posted.  This is not the most efficient way to do this sampling, but that is the question you asked.  (2) My book does cover the basics of querying SQL, but it is not exactly a tutorial for beginners.

Comment: Lindoff My query was asking to randomly select 100,000 rows from the total population of rows in the sample. Would the ORDER BY RAND() method be of use here? (2) What is the best beginner's book for learning SQL with basic Java background?

Comment: @cartesian_plane67 . . . This query is fine for the task at hand.  It is exactly the SQL Server equivalent of `order by rand()`.

Answer (score 0):

```
  select top 100000 * from table_name order by NEWID()
```

Comment: "Do not add any order by and If there are no indexes it will return random rows every time" Incorrect. Without an order by, the order is [nondeterministic](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nondeterministic_algorithm), not random.

Comment: I take my comment back, i was using a table without indexes and getting random rows without order by clause. Thanks for the correction.

Comment: You've used that word random incorrectly again. Feel free to say unexpected or surprising; but its not random. Maybe [this article](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/conor_cunningham_msft/2008/08/27/no-seatbelt-expecting-order-without-order-by/) will help to explain.